# What is the $\frac{1}{2}$ representation of $U(1)$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics, superalgebra

This may be a silly question, and so I apologize in advance. But it stems from a reading of section 2 (page 5) of the physics paper,  "[Counting chiral primaries in N=1 d=4 superconformal field theories](http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/hep-th/0510060)".

My **question** is: **What does the representation of $U(1)$ labeled as $\frac{1}{2}$ indicate?**

My question is a group-theory question, and is as such a math question, but for those unfamiliar with the context, here is some background.

1. The superconformal group for $\mathcal{N} = 1$ supersymmetry in  $d = 4$ spacetime dimensions is $SU(2,2|1)$.
2. We focus our attention on a particular subgroup of $SU(2,2|1)$, called the maximal bosonic subgroup: $SU(2,2) \times U(1)_R$. The $U(1)_R$ is known as an R-symmetry group in physics.
3. The generators of supersymmetry (the ''supercharges'') $Q$ and $Q^\dagger$ belong to representations $4_1$ and $\bar{4}_{-1}$ of $SU(2,2) \times U(1)_R$. The subscript denotes the $U(1)_R$ representation ($1$ is the fundamental, $-1$ is the anti-fundamental) and the $4$ and $\bar{4}$ are $SU(2,2)$ representations. So, so far we are labeling everything in terms of irreps of the maximal bosonic subgroup.
4. The conformal group in $d = 4$ spacetime dimensions is $SO(4,2)$, which has a covering group $SU(2,2)$.
5. We want to study a quantum field theory not in 4-dimensional Minkowski ("flat") space but on the space $\mathbb{R} \times S^3$. So one is interested in the Killing spinors of this space, and the isometries.
6. Based on (4) and (5), we restrict our attention to the subgroup $U(1) \times SO(4)$ of the conformal group, which is the isometry group of $\mathbb{R} \times S^3$.
7. The idea then is to decompose the generators in terms of representations of the isometry group $SU(2)_l \times SU(2)_r \times U(1)$ and the R-symmetry $U(1)_R$. Here we've used the fact that $\mathbb{so(4)} = \mathbb{su}(2)_l \times \mathbb{su}(2)_r$.

The claim is

$$4_1 \longrightarrow (2,1)_{\frac{1}{2},1} \oplus (1,2)_{-\frac{1}{2},1}$$
$$\bar{4}_{-1} \longrightarrow (2,1)_{-\frac{1}{2},-1} \oplus (1,2)_{\frac{1}{2},-1}$$

There are now **two** $U(1)$ subscripts: the first is for the $U(1)$ which is part of the isometry group, and the second is for the $U(1)_R$ which is the R-symmetry group. Note that the $U(1)_R$ subscript is the same on each term on the right hand side and carries over from the left.

The question posed above pertains to the *first* subscript in the above decomposition, i.e. the representation of the $U(1)$ which is part of the isometry group of the manifold.

I know that an element in $U(1)$ is represented by $e^{i\theta}$ and moreover, $U(1)$ is isomorphic to $SO(2)$. The latter made me think of the irreducible spinor representation of $SO(2)$, but that too is a real 1-dimensional representation (2d Dirac spinor with 2 complex components, but the Majorana-Weyl condition brings it down to 1 real component).

Also, if $U(1)$ is parametrized by $\left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos n\theta & \sin n\theta\\-\sin n\theta & \cos n\theta\end{array}\right)$, does $\frac{1}{2}$ simply mean that $n = 1/2$ in this representation, so that effectively, its a half rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. TL;DR: The label $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ (e.g. $q=\frac{1}{2}$) refers to the following (possibly multi-valued) 1-dimensional representation
   $$U(1)~\in~\alpha~~\stackrel{R_q}{\mapsto}~~\alpha^q ~\in~GL(1,\mathbb{C})/\sim \tag{1}$$
   of the group $U(1)$.
2. The connected component of the (global) conformal group that contains the identity element is
   $$ {\rm Conf}_0(3,1)~\cong~SO^+(4,2)/ \mathbb{Z}_2~\cong~SU(2,2)/ \mathbb{Z}_4~\cong~PSU(2,2) ,\tag{2}$$
   where 
   $$ \mathbb{Z}_2~\cong~\{\pm {\bf 1}_{6\times 6} \}, \qquad\mathbb{Z}_4~\cong~\{\pm {\bf 1}_{4\times 4},\pm i{\bf 1}_{4\times 4}\},\tag{3} $$ 
   see e.g. Ref. 2.
3. One can make a Lie group homomorphism
   $$ G~:=~SU(2)_{\ell} \times SU(2)_r \times U(1)~\ni~ (g_{\ell},g_r,\alpha)~~\stackrel{\Phi_q}{\mapsto}~~ \begin{pmatrix} \alpha^q g_{\ell} & 0 \cr 0 & \alpha^{-q} g_r \end{pmatrix}~\in~ PSU(2,2), \tag{4}$$ 
   where $$q~\in~\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}\tag{5} $$
   is a half integer (or integer).
4. If one chooses $q=\frac{1}{2}$, one may show that the Lie group homomorphism (4) is [injective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function). The product group $G$ is hence a subgroup of $PSU(2,2)$. This means that representations of $PSU(2,2)$ can be decomposed as representations of $G$.
5. *Examples:* In a hopefully obvious notation, the fundamental (multi-valued) representation decomposes as
   $$ {\bf 4}~=~ ({\bf 2}_{\ell}, {\bf 1}_r)_{\frac{1}{2}} \oplus ({\bf 1}_{\ell}, {\bf 2}_r)_{-\frac{1}{2}}, \tag{6}$$
   while the complex conjugate representation decomposes as
   $$ \overline{\bf 4}~=~ ({\bf 2}_{\ell}, {\bf 1}_r)_{-\frac{1}{2}} \oplus ({\bf 1}_{\ell}, {\bf 2}_r)_{\frac{1}{2}}, \tag{7}$$
   cf. eq. (2.1) in Ref. 1.

References:

1. C Romelsberger, [arXiv:hep-th/0510060](http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/hep-th/0510060).
2. R. Penrose & W. Rindler, *Spinors and Space-Time* Vol. 2, 1986; p. 303-304.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this just has to do with differing conventions used by physicists and mathematicians. In this context, I think the $1/2$ and $-1/2$ are $U(1)$ R-charges, and not the dimensions of the representations of $U(1)$, which obviously are all 1-dimensional.